# External keyboard connected to laptop running Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition) wont type any text after using Switch User in gnome

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard, fedora, gnome

When I click on Switch User in gnome the external keyboard no longer works. It doesn't work in the password field, and it doesn't work anywhere else such as on firefox.
The external keyboard is an amazon basics Matte Black Wired Keyboard, US QUERTY Layout keyboard. The model is MD-005.
The internal keyboard on the laptop continues to work even after the external keyboard no longer works.

I've tried downgrading the kernel but that didn't help.
I've checked my bios and fast boot is not on.
I've already disabled it on windows.
So that's probably not the problem.
I am running the OS off of a internal SSD in an external SSD case. The ssd is not in the laptop itself. The external SSD is connected by USB. There is no SSD in the laptop itself.

Below is my system info from neofetch.

```
             .',;::::;,'.                main@main-rog-strix-g513qy-g513qy.lan 
         .';:cccccccccccc:;,.            ------------------------------------- 
      .;cccccccccccccccccccccc;.         OS: Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition) x86_64 
    .:cccccccccccccccccccccccccc:.       Host: ROG Strix G513QY_G513QY 1.0 
  .;ccccccccccccc;.:dddl:.;ccccccc;.     Kernel: 6.7.6-200.fc39.x86_64 
 .:ccccccccccccc;OWMKOOXMWd;ccccccc:.    Uptime: 10 mins 
.:ccccccccccccc;KMMc;cc;xMMc:ccccccc:.   Packages: 2222 (rpm), 2 (flatpak) 
,cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cc;;WW::cccccccc,   Shell: bash 5.2.26 
:cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:ccccccc;oxOOOo;MMM0OOk.;cccccccccccc:   DE: GNOME 45.4 
cccccc:0MMKxdd:;MMMkddc.;cccccccccccc;   WM: Mutter 
ccccc:XM0';cccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc'   WM Theme: Adwaita 
ccccc;MMo;ccccc;MMW.;ccccccccccccccc;    Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
ccccc;0MNc.ccc.xMMd:ccccccccccccccc;     Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
cccccc;dNMWXXXWM0::cccccccccccccc:,      Terminal: gnome-terminal 
cccccccc;.:odl:.;cccccccccccccc:,.       CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5980HX with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 5.025GHz 
:cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc:'.         GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series 
.:cccccccccccccccccccccc:;,..            GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT/6750 XT / 6800M/6850M XT 
  '::cccccccccccccc::;,.                 Memory: 3301MiB / 15383MiB
```

I'd appreciate help.

Comment: For diagnostics purposes: does it start working when you unplug it and plug it back in after the uses-switch?

Comment: Tried plugging it back in after switching to a different user. It didn't work. Now the problem's worse, just logging in to any user disables the external keyboard. It does work at the log in screen for some reason. Also tried plugging and unplugging with login, and tried other usb port.

Comment: I think this problem occurred after updating.

Comment: Tried switching keyboards, didn't work.

Comment: I also tried plugging it into different USB ports. it didn't work with the keyboard, but did with other devices.